# CSS3 Width and Padding Issues

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a flipping 3D link menu. Since this the elements are positioned absolute I am having a hard time with of data-atrribute it seems its adding extra 1 or 2 pixels on the top and on the left side on different viewports:

Here's what it looks like on 1366 X 768 viewport:

[image]

Here's what it looks like on 1024 X 768 viewport:

[image]

Here's the view on 480 X 768 px

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
.demo-3  {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.demo-3 a {
  margin: 0 18px;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.demo-3 a span {
  background: #314559;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;

  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.1s;
   -moz-transition:   -moz-transform 0.1s;
     -o-transition:     -o-transform 0.1s;
        transition:        transform 0.1s;


}

.demo-3 a::before {   
  content: attr(data-text);
  right: -20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #314559;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  top: 0;

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;

-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.2s;
   -moz-transition:   -moz-transform 0.2s;
     -o-transition:     -o-transform 0.2s;
        transition:        transform 0.2s;

-webkit-transform:translateY(-25%);
   -moz-transform:translateY(-25%);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-25%);
     -o-transform:translateY(-25%);
        transform:translateY(-25%);
}

.demo-3 a:hover span,
.demo-3 a:focus span {
-webkit-transform:translateY(100%);
   -moz-transform:translateY(100%);
    -ms-transform:translateY(100%);
     -o-transform:translateY(100%);
        transform:translateY(100%);
}

.demo-3 a:hover::before,
.demo-3 a:focus::before {
-webkit-transform:translateY(0%);
   -moz-transform:translateY(0%);
    -ms-transform:translateY(0%);
     -o-transform:translateY(0%);
        transform:translateY(0%);
}
```

Here's what I want to attain:

1. I want to fix these extra 1px on all viewports
2. How can I create a more 3D look that looks like a box 3D when flipping?
3. How can I fix the height of the green background on all viewports. If you would resize your screen it would look the green background is kinda short especially on small viewports.

Here the jsFiddle of my codes so far: http://jsfiddle.net/52qcj2x0/6/

Any idea how to attain those two?

Comment: Maybe this can help you (check the second exemple, that might help you): http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/

Comment: @ChristopheEble: yes something like that but it must match my color scheme as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/52qcj2x0/12/
I had fixed for all browser instead of Webkit browser

Answer (score 1):

```css
div#example
  {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:#40b3df;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:5%;
    font-size:200%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="example">
  Sample Text
</div>
```

### Use Percentage(%)

The best way to remove the extra margin's is by giving all of your margin and padding in percentages(%)[even your font size]. And it is also a good practice to do so, because from this, your page will be in proportion to all other screen resolutions.

For example @bwegs :

`div#example
    {
      padding:5%;  /*or padding:5% 4.5% 5% 4.5%; */
      font-size:20%;
    }`

Then for example if the 'div#example' has width set as 50% of your screen size, then padding will be of 5% of that 50% that means the 5% is equivalent to 10% of your screen size

Comment: I have made the changes @bwegs I hope you can understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

An object appears to be in 3 Dimensions because of the shadow. The shadow of the object gives the effect of the 3rd Dimension (Z-Axis). So to give a bit of 3D effect, try giving the box-shadow style property to the Box.

The box-shadow would look something like:

```css
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
```

The parameters are horizontal depth, vertical depth, blur and color of the shadow respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer only addresses your first point.**

These appear to be rounding errors with your `::before` elements since you have `width: 100%` but no explicit width set on their parent.

You can trying setting [`.nav a`'s `display` to `block`](http://jsfiddle.net/52qcj2x0/8/) or [give those elements an explicit width](http://jsfiddle.net/52qcj2x0/9/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess [André Dion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1503994/andr%C3%A9-dion)'s solution will work for question 1.


**Solution to your 2 question:**
What you are aiming for is a [box flip](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-flipping-cube). To make it look more 3d you need to actually rotate it about X-axis and "preserve-3d" while transition takes place. Take a look at the tutorial to understand it better.


Your question 3 is not clear enough but what I understood was that you want to stack your flip boxes when the using a smaller screen size. You can take a look at the [bootstrap grid layout](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic).
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

About 3d please check this pen http://codepen.io/robbue/pen/hJDlA

And i had update code too

```css
html, 
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#container-1{
background: #314559;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3{
    text-align: center;

}

h1{
    font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 52px;
    padding: 110px 0 20px 0;
    color: #fff;

}

h3{
    font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    color: #9f9e9b;
}



a.back{
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
  color: #314559;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid #c6d0da;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}


a.next{
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    float: right;
text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 16px;
  color: #314559;
  padding: 20px 15px;
border-left: 1px solid #c6d0da;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

a.back:hover, a.next:hover{
background: #5f6f81;
color: #fff;
}


/* LINK GROUP
-------------------------------------------------*/

.link-group-1{
  background: #4E86BF;
  padding: 6.04% 0 11% 0;
  margin-top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}


.link-group-2{
  background: #FF8981;
   padding: 6.04% 0 11% 0;
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.link-group-3{
  padding: 6.04% 0 11.5% 0;
  background: #2ecc71;
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}



.link-group-4{
  background: #f8953e;
   padding: 6.04% 0 11.3% 0;
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}


i{ margin-right: 8px;}

nav { display: inline-block; }


nav a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 12px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
  outline: none;
}


.demo-3  {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.demo-3 a {
  margin: 0 18px;
  overflow: hidden;

     

}

.demo-3 a span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
background: #314559; 
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;

  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.1s;
   -moz-transition:   -moz-transform 0.1s;
     -o-transition:     -o-transform 0.1s;
        transition:        transform 0.1s;


}

.demo-3 a::before {   
  content: attr(data-text);
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #314559;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;

    
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;

-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.2s;
   -moz-transition:   -moz-transform 0.2s;
     -o-transition:     -o-transform 0.2s;
        transition:        transform 0.2s;

-webkit-transform:translateY(-25%);
   -moz-transform:translateY(-25%);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-25%);
     -o-transform:translateY(-25%);
        transform:translateY(-25%);
}

.demo-3 a:hover span,
.demo-3 a:focus span {
-webkit-transform:translateY(100%);
   -moz-transform:translateY(100%);
    -ms-transform:translateY(100%);
     -o-transform:translateY(100%);
        transform:translateY(100%);
}

.demo-3 a:hover::before,
.demo-3 a:focus::before {
-webkit-transform:translateY(0%);
   -moz-transform:translateY(0%);
    -ms-transform:translateY(0%);
     -o-transform:translateY(0%);
        transform:translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container-1">
  <h1>TESTING TESTING TESTING</h1>
  <h3>TESTING TESTING</h3>

  <div class="link-group-3">
<nav class="demo-3">
    <a href="demo1.html" data-text="Demo 1"><span>Demo 1</span> </a>
    <a href="demo2.html" data-text="Demo 2"><span>Demo 2</span></a>
    <a href="demo3.html" data-text="Demo 3"></i> <span>Demo 3</span></a>
    <a href="demo4.html" data-text="Demo 4"></i> <span>Demo 4</span></a>
</nav>







  </div>
```

About **question 3** you can use vh 
https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Answer (score 0):

**Your First Question**

It's not adding those extra pixels for me. What browser are you using? I'm using Chrome.

**Your Second**

While box-flips/preserving-3d will work a little bit, you will never really get that true 3d effect unless you use one of 2 things:

1. You could try to put a transition on the white part of your button that on mouseover takes your button from grey to white to act like a shadow. And maybe the same on your blue part.
2. The absolute hands down best way to get a 3d effect would be using WebGL. It's difficult, it works on most browsers, but it's really nice looking. This would allow you to use an actual 3d prism that you could rotate. You should use [Three.JS](http://threejs.org/).

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't it be much easier just to do:

```
.demo-3 a {
  background: #314559;
}
```

instead of just the `span` if you want the entire `<a>` to have the same background colour?